# Will composite indexes or unique indexes help with query performance?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, performance, query-performance

I need help with identifying indexes to increase performance of the following query. I'm currently using v5.5 with InnoDB. I cannot modify the query. However, I can add indexes as needed. The following indexes are currently available:

- t1.id = Primary key
- t1.status
- t2.owner
- t2.user
- t2.total

  ```
  select t1.`id` 
  from (tbl1 t1 inner join tbl2 t2 on t1.`id` = t2.`id`) 
  where (t2.`owner` = `ABC123` or t2.`user` = `ABC123`) 
    and t1.status = 1 
  order by t2.`total` 
  limit 0, 100;
  ```

Comment: What is the primary key of `t2`? Are there foreign keys between the two tables?

Comment: No FK! t2.id is PK.

Comment: Why is the data split into 2 tables? Why not just 1 table? (only asking, not implying that it would be better)

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, I don't have the answer. It's a vendor app where we have limited control to tune performance. Even if I created a view, the app would not elect to use it. The only control we have is server config and index tuning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(t2.`owner` = 'ABC123' or t2.`user` = 'ABC123')
```

This search term will force a table-scan. Composite indexes won't help.

Suppose you had a composite index on `(owner, user)`. It could do a quick lookup for `owner = 'ABC123'` but then the desired values for `user` could be anywhere in the table, not just in the subset matching the desired `owner` value. So it has to scan the whole table anyway.

Likewise if you had a composite index on `(user, owner)`. It could do a quick lookup for `user = 'ABC123'` but the same problem exists, finding the rows for `owner` will force a table-scan.

The one remaining possibility is to use [index merge union optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-optimization.html), but in my experience this doesn't work as well as you'd think.